# CSRF Protection when using the Spotify Authorization endpoint

Tags: node.js, security, oauth-2.0, jwt, spotify

I am trying to implement the ability for my users to link their Spotify account to their profiles in my app. In Spotify's official [API docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/), it says that the `STATE` field should be provided when performing a request on the `/authorize` endpoint in order to avoid CSRF attacks.

However, I don't quite understand this approach in my particular case. My client-application is a mobile app for iOS which uses JSON Web Tokens for authentication. Only after a correct token has been detected, my server returns the authorization link for the Spotify API to the client, allowing the user to authorize my app. **Therefore, CSRF requests aren't really possible, right?**

Upon successful authorization, the Spotify api calls a pre-defined callback, attaching the initially provided `STATE` field as URL query item.

I am wondering if I could just provide **the user id** of the account making the request so that the success-callback includes a reference to the user account in my database, allowing my server to quickly link the returned access & refresh tokens to it.

However, providing the user id for the `STATE` field would not comply with the [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) standard as it wouldn't be an opaque value.

Now I would like to **ask for advice** whether or not I should use the STATE field at all. If so, can I just plug in the user id of the current account as this would simplify things for me or does it have to be a randomly generated value?